# Visual Studio new project is missing files/folders

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to create a new ASP.NET Core application, but the project that is created doesn't compile because of missing dependencies.  Following another user's suggestion, I ran `dotnet restore`.  That caused the application to be able to compile and run, but now I'm getting a bunch of version conflicts, which I'd like to get rid of

Here are screenshots of how I'm creating the project.

[image]

[image]

Note the missing dependencies in the project below.

[image]

Now I run `dotnet restore`

[image]

Now the application compiles, but I get a lot of version conflicts

```
1>  Encountered conflict between 'Reference:C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.0.0\ref\netcoreapp2.0\System.AppContext.dll' and 'Reference:C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.appcontext\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.6\System.AppContext.dll'.  Choosing 'Reference:C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.0.0\ref\netcoreapp2.0\System.AppContext.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.2.0.0' is greater than '4.1.0.0'.
1>  Encountered conflict between 'Reference:C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.0.0\ref\netcoreapp2.0\System.Collections.dll' and 'Reference:C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.collections\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Collections.dll'.  Choosing 'Reference:C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.0.0\ref\netcoreapp2.0\System.Collections.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.1.0.0' is greater than '4.0.10.0'.
1>  Encountered conflict between 'Reference:C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.0.0\ref\netcoreapp2.0\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll' and 'Reference:C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.collections.concurrent\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll'.  Choosing 'Reference:C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.0.0\ref\netcoreapp2.0\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.0.14.0' is greater than '4.0.10.0'.
1>  Encountered conflict between 'Reference:C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.0.0\ref\netcoreapp2.0\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll' and 'Reference:C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\system.collections.nongeneric\4.3.0\ref\netstandard1.3\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll'.  Choosing 'Reference:C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder\microsoft.netcore.app\2.0.0\ref\netcoreapp2.0\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll' because AssemblyVersion '4.1.0.0' is greater than '4.0.1.0'.
... and so on
```

My two questions are

1. Is it normal to have to run `dotnet restore` immediately after creating a new ASP Core project?  If not, what's causing this problem for me?
2. How do I get rid of the version conflicts?

**UPDATE**

In case anyone else has the same problem and stumbles across this question, I found that for some reason, my "restore missing packages" option wasn't enabled.  Once I enabled it, I was able to build my project successfully without doing `dotnet restore` first.

[image]

Comment: try creating a dummy app using the command-line(in command-prompt) `dotnet new mvc` or `dotnet new web` . And then execute `dotnet restore` and to run `dotnet run`. If the program does not runs properly, then the Dotnet SDK might be corrupted. Thus it is affecting Visual Studio 2017 as well. If it runs well, try updating VS2017 with the required dependencies again

Comment: @o_O I tried your suggestion of `dotnet restore`, and that fixed the problem.  I ran `Tools -> Get Tools and Features` in Visual Studio and made sure that `ASP.NET and web development` is checked under `Workloads`.  Is that what you suggested doing?  Even after that, I still have the problem that I'm forced to run `dotnet restore` manually.  Is it normal to have to do that?  I'm also getting a lot of `Encountered conflict between...` errors when I compile.  I've never seen that before.

Comment: I'm sorry, can't help you further on this. I use VS Code instead of VS2017 for dotnet core app development. It is much light-weight and better. Never tried VS2017 apart from desktop apps.

Comment: Are you using some outdated Visual Studio 2017 or one of its extension?

Comment: Not that I know of.  Under `Extensions and Updates`, the only things that are listed are AWS Toolkit and Azure Analytics Tools.  I also just downloaded and installed the latest version of .NET Core SDK (2.1.3).

Comment: And using Visual Studio 15.5? .NET Core 2.0.x SDK installed?

Comment: @Tseng Yes I'm using Visual Studio 15.5.2.  As far as I know, I've got the .NET Core SDK installed correctly.  `Microsoft .NET Core SDK - 2.1.3 (x64)`  shows up in my `Programs and Features`.  Is the 64-bit causing the problem maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Nothing to fear. Absolutely normal. And when you call `dotnet build` at command line, `dotnet restore` would be called implicitly. That's a .NET SDK 2.0 change. If you are forced to run `dotnet restore` manually, that becomes another issue, which means your .NET Core SDK does not take effect. You need to learn `global.json` and create such a file in your project to force using the latest SDK on this machine, like [Scott Hanselman wrote](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithMultipleNETCoreSDKsBothProjectjsonAndMsbuildcsproj.aspx).

> Visual Studio 2017 might require you to use Restore NuGet Packages menu item.
>   Visual Studio for Mac or JetBrains Rider would automatically restore the packages.

2. Nobody tries to get rid of that. MSBuild has its internal logic on calculation and clearly [this issue has been known and harmless (except your eyes) so far](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/608).

Do make good use of Google and GitHub, and you can find all the officially information made public by Microsoft.

The presence of `project.assets.json` is an indication that the legacy of `package.json` is still there in the build process.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  In regards to point #1, building the project in VS doesn't create the missing `project.assets.json` file, but `dotnet build` does.  Why is that?  I figured the two of those were equivalent?  Another question: since .NET Core 2 is using .csproj instead of .json, why is this `project.assets.json` file required (and if it's required, why isn't Visual Studio creating it when I create my project)?